# Infragistics upgrade of winforms controls

Tags: winforms, infragistics

We are currently using Infragistics winforms controls v8. We are not satisfied with the performance of our application and want to speed it up. Is it worth trying to upgrade these Infragistics components to latest version? Or are they even more bloated now?

thanks in advance

Comment: what were you editing skaffman?

Comment: @skaffman edited your question tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We upgraded from 2008 to 2010.3 a few months ago. The upgrade process itself posed no problems. In my experience there has been no perceivable performance improvement between the 2008.3 controls and the current 2011.1 controls at either design or runtime, however we didn't upgrade for performance reasons, mainly for support reasons.

As the 2008 controls are now out of support, upgrading to the latest version would certainly help bring you up to date with the latest patches.

Comment: Note: I'm sure there *are* performance improvements in specific use cases that we possibly don't hit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing some performance issues in your Windows Forms application I would like to suggest you looking into one very useful article which explains some of the ways that might be followed in order of improving the performance of your application:

http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/15306.aspx?PageIndex=1